# In Gaussian Process regression is there a way to force the prior slope to be positive when using a linear kernel?

Tags: regression, gaussian-process, nonparametric-regression

I'm doing Gaussian process regression on some data $X$ with low sample size, using a squared exponential kernel. From domain knowledge I know that outside the range of my data the regressed function should increase when $x \to -\infty$ and decrease when $x \to \infty$.

If there is plenty of data I can get wanted behavior by adding a linear kernel centered at the mean of my training locations. However, when fewer training points are available the slope of the sample functions far from the training points may have the wrong sign. That is, instead of a decreasing large scale trend, I get an increasing one.

So, is there a way around this problem by modifying the linear part of the kernel or some other means?

I'm not an expert in GPs so please bare with me if the question is naive. Thanks!